# Best practices for updating local JSON data file in Swift app?

Tags: ios, json, swift

My app will ship with a local JSON file for the data, so that everything functions properly offline (because the region the app is based on is hit or miss on connections).  I would like to be able to update the local file from time to time with an updated version that is hosted on a server.

Should I download the updated file and overwrite the local file with it, or is there a way to check to see if the file has been updated before downloading?

Also, what event would be best to do these type of tasks on?  Downloading the file and overwriting the local copy every time the app runs seems like overkill, but I don't really know how I would go about checking the server file to see if the file is newer before downloading.

I'm new to programming in general, so I don't really know the best practices way to handle something like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general question and there's a lot of implementation details. Try to break things down into several more specific questions.

But a common pattern is to use versioning. That is, at the top of the file is a version attribute. Every time the server updates the file, it religiously increments the version. The client can do a tiny web-endpoint JSON query for just the version number and get back a single integer. It can read its own file on App startup, cache the local version number, and periodically compare.

How often to compare is completely App specific, but the version query will be lightweight and of constant size regardless of how big the file gets.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm more looking for just a best practice for updating the file, not really looking for code or any specific problem.  Thanks for your reply.  It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Maybe add some tags. This discussion is quite independent of iOS and Swift. It's really any mobile platform where you want to save bandwidth and battery.